# Laravel: Get values of checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel, validation, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes in the following code:

```
@foreach($camera_video as $video)
  <input type="checkbox" name="camera_video" value="{{$video->id}}"> <label>{{$video->name}}</label>
@endforeach
```

I would like to see which checkboxes have been checked by the user. I just need the id (value) to store. What is the best way to do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should update name of your checkbox input to `camera_video[]` as array and you are good to go. You will get input array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="camera_video[]" value="{{$video->id}}"> <label>{{$video->name}}</label>
```

If you are using Laravel 5.x.x you should use Request object:

```
public function yourMethod(Request $request)
{
    $cameraVideo = $request->input('camera_video');
    ...
}
```

Comment: i almost got it. in my controller, where i handle the request. I shoul use $camera_video = Input::get('camera_video'); -> the funny thing is, when i write this line i get a Http Error 500 with no hint to any mistake...

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: i installed a new project, should be 5.4. But i think i have a problem with the storage write permission. Trying to figure it out

Comment: If your version is 5 or up you should use Request Object... I'll update my answer

Comment: that worked for me. THX. but i still need to figure out why i am getting a 500 server error when i have a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Input::all()
```

or

```
Input::get('camera_video')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use has to function on the request object to check the value of the checkbox is exist and is not in the request like below;

```
public function store(Request $request){
        if($request->has('terms')){
            //Checkbox checked
        }else{
            //Checkbox not checked
        }
}
```

for multiple;

```
  public function store(Request $request){
        if(in_array('Mango', $request->get('fruits'))){
            //User like Mango
        }else{
           //User does not like Mango
        }
    }

$request->get('fruits') // this will return the array;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the name as an array so that you can fetch the input as array in Laravel. Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="camera_video[]" value="{{$video->id}}"> <label>{{$video->name}}</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the multiple checkboxes in a view, you can do it like this.

```
@foreach($camera_video as $video)
   <input type="checkbox" name="camera_videos[]" value="{{$video->id}}"> 
   <label>{{$video->name}}</label>
@endforeach
```

Inside your controller, you can do it like @Buglinjo's answer or else simply use a `foreach loop`. **You will get the value of checked checkboxes only**

```
$camera_videos = $request->input('camera_videos');
foreach ($camera_videos as $camera_video) {
    //you can do whatever you want. I am saving it in MySqli DB
    $table = new Model;
    $table->video_id = $camera_video;
    $table->save();
}
```