# Can't get inputs from li in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have list in each li i have input field but when i send data can't get value of those inputs

## blade

```
@foreach($options as $group => $option)

// another options here with name="dropdown" //

// And this data won't send
<div class="tt-swatches-container">
    <div class="tt-wrapper">
        <div class="tt-title-options">{{$group}}:</div>
        <ul class="tt-list-inline tt-options-swatch options-large">
            @foreach($option as $opt)
            <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                <label for="{{$opt->id}}">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{$group}}" value="{{$opt->title}}" id="{{$opt->id}}" />
                    {{$opt->title}}
                </label>
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

## result

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "kanCHxEv96MWih4TaXTKSjHYu8gDdWs1YLDCWiv0"
  "dropdown" => "title 44"
  "quantity" => "1"
  //here should be another option named color!
]
```

> this data above it should be contain `name="{{$group}}"` and it's
>   value (in this case `name="{{$group}}" == colors`

[image: one]

Any idea?

## Update

my form

```
<form method="post" class="form-default" action="{{route('addingItem', $product->id)}}">
    @csrf

    @if(count($options)>0)
    <!-- options -->
    <div class="tt-swatches-container">
        @foreach($options as $group => $option)
        @if($group == 'color')
            <div class="tt-wrapper">
                <div class="tt-title-options">{{$group}}:</div>
                <ul class="tt-list-inline tt-options-swatch options-large">
                    @foreach($option as $opt)
                    <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                        <label style="background-color: {{$opt->color}}" class="options-color" for="{{$opt->id}}">
                            <input type="radio" name="{{$group}}" value="{{$opt->title}}" id="{{$opt->id}}" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @elseif($group == 'dropdown')
            <div class="tt-swatches-container">
                <div class="tt-wrapper">
                    <div class="tt-title-options">{{$group}}:</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="{{$group}}" class="form-control">
                            @foreach($option as $opt)
                                <option>{{$opt->title}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="tt-swatches-container">
                <div class="tt-wrapper">
                    <div class="tt-title-options">{{$group}}:</div>
                    <ul class="tt-list-inline tt-options-swatch options-large">
                        @foreach($option as $opt)
                        <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                            <label for="{{$opt->id}}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="{{$group}}" value="{{$opt->title}}" id="{{$opt->id}}" />
                                {{$opt->title}}
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- options -->
    @endif

    <div class="tt-wrapper">
        <div class="tt-row-custom-01  tt-responsive-lg">
            <div class="col-item">
                <div class="tt-input-counter style-01">
                    <span class="minus-btn"></span>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="5">
                    <span class="plus-btn"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-item">
                <button type="submit" data-id="{{$product->id}}" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="icon-f-39"></i>ADD TO CART</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

## Update 2

dd of `$options`

```
Collection {#3133 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "color" => Collection {#3127 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    "dropdown" => Collection {#3128 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    "radio" => Collection {#3129 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

## Update 3

Outer HTML

```
<form method="post" class="form-default" action="http://shopping.dev.com/addingItem/22">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="kanCHxEv96MWih4TaXTKSjHYu8gDdWs1YLDCWiv0">
    <!-- options -->
    <div class="tt-swatches-container">
        <div class="tt-wrapper">
            <div class="tt-title-options">color:</div>
            <ul class="tt-list-inline tt-options-swatch options-large">
                <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                    <label style="background-color: #e74c3c" class="options-color" for="28">
                        <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="28">
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                    <label style="background-color: #2980b9" class="options-color" for="29">
                        <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="29">
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>                                                                                          
        <div class="tt-swatches-container">
            <div class="tt-wrapper">
                <div class="tt-title-options">dropdown:</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="dropdown" class="form-control">
                        <option>title 33</option>
                        <option>title 44</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="tt-wrapper">
                <div class="tt-title-options">radio:</div>
                <ul class="tt-list-inline tt-options-swatch options-large">
                    <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                        <label for="36">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="hi" id="36">
                            hi
                        </label>
                    </li>
                        <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                        <label for="37">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="hii" id="37">
                            hii
                        </label>
                    </li>
                        <li class="tt-list-inline-item">
                        <label for="38">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="bye" id="38">
                            bye
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- options -->

    <div class="tt-wrapper">
        <div class="tt-row-custom-01  tt-responsive-lg">
            <div class="col-item">
                <div class="tt-input-counter style-01">
                    <span class="minus-btn"></span>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="5">
                    <span class="plus-btn"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-item">
                <button type="submit" data-id="22" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="icon-f-39"></i>ADD TO CART</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966620/laravel-get-value-of-checkbox

Comment: Maybe you never hit the `else`. Could you `dd($options)`?

Comment: @Mozammil sure i will but just to know as my image I have all 3 types of options in my view (color,select,checkbox) so i did hit else part as well.

Comment: @Mozammil updated

Comment: Interesting. Should work. Could you show us the controller?

Comment: @Mozammil `$options = $product->options->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
            return [$item->group->type => $item];
        });`

Comment: @Mozammil i think whatever the problem is, is coming from inputs inside `<li>`

Comment: I meant the controller where you are handling the form request?

Comment: oh, simply i dd requests for now `dd($request->all());` nothing special yet waiting to get all data then :D

Comment: If you inspect the inputs in the browser, do they all have the `name` and `value` attributes set correctly?

Comment: Yes they do....

Comment: can you add the generated form (from view source or the inspector)? I suspect its because you have multiple of the same name (it should be an array form). There is no chance its related to it being inside a <li>

Comment: @Chris updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have provided seems to be correct. There could be a few issues at play though.

First, take a look at your raw, output code, here: https://codepen.io/cjke/pen/vbxRwb?editors=1000

Fill out all the fields and hit submit, and you will see codepen spitting those values out correctly. So your finally rendered form is doing everything it should do (this is your exact code at play, the only change I made was removing the action).

[image]

So, my first guess is, that you're not submitting data. Ie: you're not actually filling out the fields when submitting as a user, which will leave you with `radio` and `color` not being set (vs being empty). If this is the case, you need to handle "default" state.

My second guess, is you have some validation occurring before the form submission that is perhaps messing with it. But that is pretty unlikely.

My third guess, but less likely, is that you have some application specific middleware stripping submission data. Unlikely, unless someone else in your team wrote it?

If its really none of those three, you will need to update your question to include your controller code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ideas, actually i found the issue was related to your second guess, there was a javascript code which was adding class to the parent li to get designs now that I have removed that js code it seems to be working however now my template design is messed up. I've tried lot's of ways from css to js in order to add again `active` class in parent `li` all failed. **here is the code that I removed** https://www.codepile.net/pile/jM6Q3qxW maybe you can understand something of it so i can again add `active` class to parent li's without messing data sends?

Comment: Seems like that would be a new question. However not sure why an active class (or lack of) would restrict data submission. Looking at your code though (in the link), it seems the li click event handler is maybe preventing it to reach the actual input?

Comment: probably yes, i was suspicious to li issue i guess i was right :) (somehow)

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand your `color` object when you do `dd($options)`?

Based on the contents of that `li`, it is using the ff vars:

```
{{ $group }}
{{ $opt->id }} //a number
{{ $opt->title }} //a color title/name?
{{ $opt->color }} //a color title/name?
```

Just trying here, but it could be possible that either `title` or `color` doesn't exist within $opt